# How do I update the schema for hive orc table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, orc

I created a hive external table stored in orc format.

```
create external table test
(first_name string,
last_name string)
partitioned by (year int, month int) 
stored as orc location "\usr\tmp\orc_files'
```

I then inserted some data into the location.
When I perform a select query on this table, I get the right results.

Next I added a new column to the table using:

```
alter table test add columns(middle_name string);
```

now, when I try to do

```
select * from test;
```

I get an error:

```
17/05/25 11:52:23 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: select * from test
17/05/25 11:52:23 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 580, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.sql(sqlQuery), self)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o55.sql.
: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
        at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalRelation.scala:39)
```

Can someone help me with this? Why am I not able to change the schema for an orc table?

Comment: Did you try the same query outside of spark?

Comment: Yes, I just ran the alter table command in beeline, its completes fine. but then when do a select *, i get error. I think this error is because of the orc format. When i have the format as avro, everything works fine.

Comment: just fyi, once i add the new column, the show create table command shows the table as stored as textformat instead of orc format. I am not sure why.

Comment: Hmm. I haven't recently modified a ORC table, so I don't know about that